# Inappropriate line break in R Markdown ioslide_presentation

Tags: r, markdown, line-breaks, ioslides

In `ioslide_presentation`, each time I use a single `$` to insert a math expression in my code it breaks the line which is really annoying.

R markdown:

[image]

Wlide result:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a small example?  A complete presentation with just one slide that we could run would be best, in case the problem isn't where you expect it.

Comment: like the above comment says, show your work. There's not much to work with here.

Comment: When you compile the slide, use the "inspect" feature of Chrome and see what the css of the linebreak is and then remove it.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: We can't run those PNG images you posted, and you didn't include the header for the presentation.